How do i install a new replacement sink that is smaller than my old sink?
I have a chrome sink that is a little over 32" in length and 19 inches and width. My new sink I bought is 31.49" in length and 18.1 inches in width.
So it's a little smaller both ways. How do I add more onto my counter on either side, so I don't have to hire a professional? The depth under my cupboard below the sink fits perfect. So I'm only concerned about the width and length.

Even though it is smaller, does it cover the old cut out? Or does it try to, or perhaps, succeeds in dropping through the cut out?

Can you return the sink and get one more appropriately sized? It’s much easier to cut a little than to fill in a hole.

Need more info.  What is the counter material?  Is the old sink drop in, or undermount?  Is the new sink drop in, or undermount?

Two options.

fit a new counter top with the correct size hole

glue strips on the edges of the hole to make it smaller
I would add one single long strip across the back but would put 2 strips ie 1 on each side each taking half the gap to make up which may possibly not show. Make sure the sink has sufficient area to rest on though.



3: install some sort of trim plate to bridge the existing hole, with cut-out for sink. 4. Return the unused sink and exchange for one that fits...
